# how would I detect a non-overlap of two time periods?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a user input form where user select the date in (YYYY-mm-dd) format, and start time in (H:i) and end time in (H:i) format, or assume i have three variable with following values.

```
$date      = '2012-11-22';
$startTime = '1:00';
$endTime   = '4:00';
```

i now have to compare this values with existing array of values. my existing array look like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [start_datetime] => 2012-11-22 02:30:00
            [end_datetime] => 2012-11-22 05:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [start_datetime] => 2012-11-22 00:00:00
            [end_datetime] => 2012-11-22 02:30:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [start_datetime] => 2012-11-22 05:00:00
            [end_datetime] => 2012-11-22 08:00:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [start_datetime] => 2012-11-22 08:00:00
            [end_datetime] => 2012-11-22 11:00:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [start_datetime] => 2012-11-22 11:00:00
            [end_datetime] => 2012-11-22 17:00:00
        )

)
```

i have to check if the user input selected **[date, startTime, and endTime]** has any of the slots already booked in the given array of time slots. from what i see the solution is to first split and match the date, if it matches the date then time needs to be matched accordingly. i am confused about how to go with it. i hope to get some simple solution from you guys :)

thank you.

**UPDATE:**
i tried doing this way.

```
$arenaSurfaceBooking = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'start_datetime' => '2012-11-22 02:30:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2012-11-22 05:00:00',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'start_datetime' => '2012-11-22 00:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2012-11-22 02:30:00',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'start_datetime' => '2012-11-22 05:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2012-11-22 08:00:00',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'start_datetime' => '2012-11-22 08:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2012-11-22 11:00:00',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'start_datetime' => '2012-11-22 11:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2012-11-22 17:00:00',
    )
);

foreach($arenaSurfaceBooking as $booking) {
    $bookedDateTimestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($booking['start_datetime'])));
    $inputDateTimestamp  = strtotime($context['date']);
    $bookedStartTime     = strtotime(date('H:i', strtotime($booking['start_datetime'])));
    $bookedEndTime       = strtotime(date('H:i', strtotime($booking['end_datetime'])));
    $userStartTime       = strtotime(date('H:i', strtotime($context['start_datetime'])));
    $userEndTime         = strtotime(date('H:i', strtotime($context['end_datetime'])));
    if( $bookedDateTimestamp == $inputDateTimestamp) {
        if( $userEndTime <= $bookedStartTime || $userStartTime >= $bookedEndTime) {
            echo 'i am booked';
        }
    }
}
```

it's not working.

Comment: i hope i have not complicated the question, if you don't understand please let me know ill try to explain it in better way.

Comment: What/How have you tried?

Comment: @PLB i tried splitting the date and comparing the date first. i am confused on how i should be comparing the time.

Comment: For starters, you should use strtotime() to make easy comparisons.

Comment: @Jack: There's no need. This format is directly comparable in string form.

Comment: @jack i understand that. i said i am confused about the logic not the implementation.

Comment: @Jon his times at the top are missing hour padding, if this comes from user input you'd have to reformat at the very least.

Comment: is the existing Array data goten from a query to a DB? I mean it would be much easier to check with a direct SELECT to the DB if that's the case

Comment: A trick that usually works is by asking: how would I detect a non-overlap of two time periods? Then negate that.

Comment: @Naryl yeah i got it from database, and the array names corresponds to database column.

Comment: @Jack do you suggest, i change the tile to that?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar you've mentioned two times start time, is it true or later one is end time?

Comment: @MohitMehta the other is $endTime, i have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the user date/time is formatted like so:

```
$date      = '2012-11-22';
$startTime = '01:00'; // note the extra '0' in front
$endTime   = '04:00';

$userStartTime = "$date $startTime";
$userEndTime = "$date $endTime";
```

Finding overlaps is done this way:

```
$overlaps = 0;
foreach ($block as $block) {
    if ($userStartTime < $block['end_datetime'] && $userEndTime > $block['start_datetime']) {
        ++$overlaps;
    }
}

// if $overlaps > 0 -> there's a booking in the way
```

This is basically taking a non-overlap condition like this:

```
$userEndTime <= $block['start_datetime'] || $userStartTime >= $block['end_datetime']
```

And simply swap the conditions.

This can easily be written into SQL as well to reduce the network overhead between database and application.

Comment: then i wouldn't mind going mysql way, i think i will open another question for it. thank you jack BTW :)

Comment: will it be a problem if i have no zero in front of time?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Maybe MySQL can handle the missing zero when comparing against `DATETIME`, but when you compare dates as strings like in my answer you need all date/time formats to be identical.

Comment: is it not possible for me to convert the date time to unix timestamp using strtotime and then compare it? i have been trying to do it that way.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar If your database fields are `DATETIME` you should try first; otherwise: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($your_funky_date))`.

Comment: yeah, tried doing that, i still have the problem, the problem is while comparing date, would you like to see if i update my question?

Comment: I don't know what you did there, my answer doesn't even look like that. I would suggest trying my answer first and rewriting it to use SQL.

Comment: here is the follow up question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513516/find-if-time-slots-are-available-in-database-table#13513583

Answer (score 1):

Since the existing array comes from a SQL query:

```
$date      = '2012-11-22';
$startTime = '1:00'; 
$endTime   = '4:00';

if(strlen($startTime==4)){$startTime="0".$startTime;}
if(strlen($endTime==4)){$endTime="0".$startTime;}

$query="SELECT id FROM table WHERE start_datetime='$date $startTime:00' OR end_datetime='$date $endtimeTime:00'";
```

If the query returns something, the `id` returned have it booked!

If you want to know if any of the db info matches both datetimes just replace the `OR` with a `AND`.

If you want to know if the user time period is between any of the entries of the DB:

```
$query="SELECT id FROM table WHERE (start_datetime>='$date $startTime:00' AND start_datetime<='$date $endTime:00') OR (end_datetime<='$date $starttimeTime:00' AND end_datetime>='$date $endtimeTime:00') OR (start_datetime<='$date $startTime:00' AND end_datetime>='$date $starttimeTime:00')";
```

Comment: there is still the problem, what if the selected starttime is 1 and endtime is 5, and in database i have 2 to 4 stores, it should still return true logically.

Comment: yup, I edited the last query and it should work with that input.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out... and modify it according to your requirement to match all existing time... I've matched only one for you...

```
$date = '2012-11-22';
$startTime = '2:30';
$endTime = '4:00';

$existing[] = 
        array
        (
            'id' => 1,
            'start_datetime' => '2012-11-22 02:30:00',
            'end_datetime' => '2012-11-22 05:00:00'
        );

$UserStartTime = strtotime($date." ".$startTime);
$UserEndTime = strtotime($date." ".$endTime);

$ExistingStartTime = strtotime($existing[0]['start_datetime']);
$ExistingEndTime = strtotime($existing[0]['end_datetime']);

if($UserStartTime >= $ExistingStartTime && $UserEndTime <= $ExistingEndTime)
{
    echo "BOOKED";
}
else
{
    echo "NOT BOOKED";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
$date = '2012-11-22';
$startTime= '1:00:00'; // padded two zero
$endTime = '4:00:00'; // padded two zero

$start_datetime = $date. " ".(strlen(intval(substr($startTime,0,2))) > 1 ? $startTime : "0".$startTime);

$end_datetime = $date. " ".(strlen(intval(substr($endTime,0,2))) > 1? $endTime : "0".$endTime);
for($i = 0;$i<count($your_array);$i++)
{
    if($your_array[$i]['start_datetime'] == $start_datetime)
    {
        // Start date Found
    }
    if($your_array[$i]['end_datetime'] == $end_datetime)
    {
        // Start end Found
    }
}
```