# find if time slots are available in database table

Tags: mysql, database

i have the following database table with columns.

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | start_datetime      | end_datetime        | arena_surface_id |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 | 2012-11-22 02:30:00 | 2012-11-22 05:00:00 |                2 |
|  2 | 2012-11-22 00:00:00 | 2012-11-22 02:30:00 |                2 |
|  3 | 2012-11-22 05:00:00 | 2012-11-22 08:00:00 |                2 |
|  4 | 2012-11-22 08:00:00 | 2012-11-22 11:00:00 |                2 |
|  5 | 2012-11-22 11:00:00 | 2012-11-22 17:00:00 |                2 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

with the user input of date, start time, and end time, i want to find out if there are any slots booked for particular arena_surface_id within the given period of time.

for example if user input is.

```
start_datetime : 2012-11-22 6:00
end_datetime : 2012-11-22 9:00
arena_surface_id : 2
```

i want to know if there are any rows which matches time slot between 6:00 and 9:00 for the given date time (in the above example it should match).

what would be the proper mysql query for this?

This is actually a follow up question for this [how would I detect a non-overlap of two time periods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512501/how-would-i-detect-a-non-overlap-of-two-time-periods/13513064#comment18497118_13513064)

**UPDATE**

@March this is what it returns when i use your query.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    start_datetime, 
    end_datetime, 
    arena_surface_id 
FROM 
    gce_arena_surface_booking 
WHERE 
    (start_datetime BETWEEN '2012-11-22 04:00:00' AND '2012-11-22 09:00:00')
OR 
    (end_datetime BETWEEN '2012-11-22 4:00:00' AND '2012-11-22 9:00:00')


+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | start_datetime      | end_datetime        | arena_surface_id |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 | 2012-11-22 02:30:00 | 2012-11-22 05:00:00 |                2 |
|  3 | 2012-11-22 05:00:00 | 2012-11-22 08:00:00 |                2 |
|  4 | 2012-11-22 08:00:00 | 2012-11-22 11:00:00 |                2 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

the middle record does not match the condition, and still fetches it.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE (startTime BETWEEN 'yourStartImput' AND 'yourEndImput') OR (endTime BETWEEN 'yourStartImput' AND 'yourEndImput')
```

So you check if there's a match that starts or ends between your input.

For your comment, your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE ((startTime BETWEEN 'yourStartImput' AND 'yourEndImput') 
  OR (endTime BETWEEN 'yourStartImput' AND 'yourEndImput')) 
  AND arena_surface_id = 1
```

Comment: i tried using this way and it gives me syntax error . `SELECT *  FROM gce_arena_surface_booking WHERE (start_datetime BETWEEN 2012-11-22 4:00 AND 2012-11-22 9:00) OR (end_datetime BETWEEN 2012-11-22 4:00 AND 2012-11-22 9:00);`

Comment: You need single quotes around your dates

Comment: yeah, it fetches now, but in between there is one wrong record being fetched. ill update my question to what it returns, you can have a look into the question.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Can you explain why the middle record is wrong plz?

Comment: i was wrong it is perfect, however i need to add another condition stating `WHERE arena_surface_id = 1` simply appending it to last does not work.

Comment: You can reduce to two conditions: `'yourStartInput' < endTime AND 'yourEndInput' > startTime` - give or take inclusiveness.

Comment: i know it's very late, but how do you translate this with Laravel Eloquent?